# RDP session: Win to Win: How to disable clipboard sharing in running RDP session?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Win 10 -> Win 8.1 in this case

I know I can set clipboard sharing on or off before I start the session.

But once the session is running (and I don't want to interrupt it, because important stuff is running that I can't interrupt), how do I turn off clipboard sharing?

Why is this important: Because a guy is remoted in to the remote system and I need to disconnect our clipboards which are interfering with each other, but I gotta watch him....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is.... once the session is running you can't change it. You have to disconnect RDP, turn off the clipboard sharing setting, and reconnect.

There seems to be no other way.

Comment: Wow that's really dumb!

Answer (score 3):

Windows RDP client does not provide a functionality for temporary disabling clipboard synchronization, but there is a workaround which stops clipboard sharing of an active RDP session:

On server side inside the RDP session a program named `rdpclip.exe` is running which is responsible for clipboard synchronization in both directions. If you kill that program, clipboard synchronization is stopped (e.g. via Task Manager). As far as I know Windows will not restart this program on it's own.

To re-enable clipboard synchronization simply start `rdpclip.exe` again, e.g. by performing

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> `rdpclip` <kbd>Enter</kbd>